# Recessed lighting issue

Tags: electrical

I was doing some work for a customer and I installed two recessed lights in her living room.

She called back and said she wanted two more.

I added the two and it was a slight delay on the two new ones.

What’s the problem ?

Comment: Are they the same brand/model? Even if they are, there can be variances as LEDs are not simple resistors with a very well defined profile (aka incandescent bulbs). They have complex driver circuits and if they are not tuned exactly the same (which is all based on factory installed components - not much you can change about them) they will behave a little differently.

Comment: Can you fit all four fixtures with the same brand and model of light bulbs and then re-evaluate?

Comment: What does "it was a slight delay on the two new ones" mean? I took that to mean that there was a delay in completing the installation for your customer, but, since we can't help you with that, I'd guess that's probably not what you mean...